# E-mail as required during iOS registration

Tags: iphone, ios, registration

I'm working on iOS application that requires user to register first. One of the design requests is to ask user to provide e-mail address that should be validated by the back-end server afterwards.

I've been warned that Apple forbids iOS applications to require e-mail from the users. However, I'm unable to find any reference to such a statement anywhere on the Apple web sites.

Is this statement true? Can I require e-mail address to be entered or not? I need real reference to this if it is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can. Most of the applications that need a registration will ask the user for a email/password pair or a userName/password. As far as I am concern, and the amount of application I have been doing I never had any issue with this kind of requirement.

Still:

> 17.2: Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected
>
> We found that your app requires customers to register with personal
>   information to access non-account-based features, which is not in
>   compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Apps cannot require user registration prior to allowing access to app
>   features and content that are not associated specifically to the user.
>   User registration that requires the sharing of personal information
>   must be optional or tied to account-specific functionality.
>   Additionally, the requested information must be relevant to the
>   features.
>
> Although guideline 11.6 of the App Store Review Guidelines requires an
>   application to make subscription content available to all the iOS
>   devices owned by a single user, it is not appropriate to force user
>   registration to meet this requirement; such user registration must be
>   made optional.
>
> It would be appropriate to make it clear to the user that registering
>   will enable them to access the content from any of their iOS devices,
>   and to provide them a way to register at any time, if they wish to
>   later extend access to additional iOS devices

Comment: Have you ever required an e-mail. Having it as optional entry would pass I guess, but I'm more concerned in actually using e-mail for other features (such as password recovery, etc).

Comment: In that case, as stated: `User registration that requires the sharing of personal information must be optional or tied to account-specific functionality.` Twitter or FB only makes sense, if you provide an email/password pair. So you can have access to your own stuff. Providing an email for spam purposes (for example) will make Apple reject your app.